# Last line doesn't print?

Tags: java

When I run the program everything works fine until I get to the last line where I want to to multiply the price of gas depending on the type, however that part does not print out.

```
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

double R = 2.19;
double M = 2.49;
double P = 2.71;

System.out.println("What type of gas?");
System.out.println("(R)egular:    2.19");
System.out.println("(M)idgrade:   2.49");
System.out.println("(P)remium:    2.71");

 String gastype;
 gastype = S.nextLine();

 System.out.println("How many gallons?");
 double gallons;
 gallons = S.nextDouble();

 if ((R * gallons) == 0)
 {
   System.out.println("You owe: " +R * gallons+ "");
 }

 if ((M * gallons) == 0)
 {
   System.out.println("You owe: " +M * gallons+ "");
 }

 if ((P * gallons) == 0)
 {
   System.out.println("You owe: " +P * gallons+ "");
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your code snippet to print `total price`, it should be something like:

```
double total;

// check for user input of "gas type"
// calculate total = gas type * gallons
if (gasType.equals("R")) {
    total = R * gallons;
} else if (gasType.equals("M")) {
    total = M * gallons;
} else if (gasType.equals("P")) {
    total = P * gallons;
} else {
    System.out.println("Invalid type of gas");
    return;
}

System.out.println("You owe: %f", total);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statements will only execute if gallons = 0. Not only that, but you aren’t checking to see which gas the customer wanted. You’re essentially ignoring the `gastype` altogether for your final answer.

Try this `if` statement as an example

```
if (gasType.equals(“Regular”) {
  //Stuff you want to print
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
double R = 2.19;
double M = 2.49;
double P = 2.71;

System.out.println("What type of gas?");
System.out.println("(R)egular:    2.19");
System.out.println("(M)idgrade:   2.49");
System.out.println("(P)remium:    2.71");

 String gastype;
 gastype = S.nextLine();

 System.out.println("How many gallons?");
 double gallons;
 gallons = S.nextDouble();

 if ((gasType == 'R') {
   System.out.println("You owe: " +R * gallons+ "");
 }
 else if (gasType == 'M') {
   System.out.println("You owe: " +M * gallons+ "");
 }
 else if (gasType == 'P') {
   System.out.println("You owe: " +P * gallons+ "");
 }
 else {
   System.out.println("Wrong GasType")
 }
}
```